# Javascript push method not working

Tags: javascript, json, jquery

I can't push elements to works array.  Console log is returning proper objects, but they won't be pushed to the array... Here is my code:

```
var works = new Array();
    $(window).ready(function()
    {       

        $.getJSON('AJAX/getWorks.php', function(data) {
          $.each(data, function(key, val) {
             console.log(val);
             works.push(val);
          });
        });
        console.log(works);
    });
```

And the json object:

```
Object
date: "2012-04-08 17:53:58"
description: "sadasd"
id: "2"
link: "sadasd"
name: "dsad"
objects: null
position: "2"
__proto__: Object
```

Anybody see what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance for answers...

Comment: Is the missing closing parenthesis a copy/paste error?

Comment: How do you know they are not in the array ? Where are you outputting the array ? Are you sure you are not logging the array before the ajax request has finished ?

Comment: What if you change your debug statement to `console.log(val, works)`?

Comment: Yes, data is an array and val is the object...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're logging the array too early in your code. The `console.log` will run before the ajax request has finished because `ajax` is asynchronous.

```
    $.getJSON('AJAX/getWorks.php', function(data) {
              $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                 console.log(val);
                 works.push(val);
              });
              console.log(works); // move this here so the array is logged after the ajax request finishes. 
            });
```

EDIT

If you want to use that variable after the ajax request you can do the following

Create a function to house the ajax request

```
function getWorks() 
{
    return  $.getJSON('AJAX/getWorks.php', function(data) {
              $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                 works.push(val);
              }); 
}
```

Then you can do the following to assure that the ajax request is complete.

```
 $.when( getWorks() ).then(function(){ 
     // you can access the array in here because the ajax has finished executing
 });
```

Comment: Yes, the logging code in the OP is running before the AJAX call is completing.

Comment: No i don't think so... I am logging that inside document.ready, just after the getJson function, so the object has to be already initialized...

Comment: is no one looking at my example?! you people are unbelievable! It is this example minus the JSON (which cannot be tested properly) and includes the global variable. sheesh.

Comment: Thank you, thats what i was looking for! when...then... i was missing that part! thanks a lot!